# MDX left in SSRS report query

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, mdx, olap

I want to filter some Product codes from report in SSRS using LEFT() and I got problem.

This is piece of my query:

```
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Plan type].[Plan type].&[100000002] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@ProducersName, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@CalendarTime, CONSTRAINED) )  ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( LEFT([Product].[Product code],3) <> 'ALE')  ON COLUMNS --codes that I want to filter out
FROM ( SELECT ( LEFT([Product].[Product code],3) <> 'DBN' )  ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( LEFT([Product].[Product code],3) <> 'DBR' )  ON COLUMNS
FROM [Sales]))))))
```

Problem is, I can't get it working because I get some syntax errors on those LEFT's with Product Codes. Rest works perfectly.
Can you help me?

Comment: is that sql or mdx I don't understand it - why do you have 6 COLUMNS axes ?

Comment: @whytheq - I guess you figured it anyway - these are nested sub selects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please come out of the SQL world, this is MDX.

`LEFT([Product].[Product code],3)` makes no sense. What you needed probably would have to be `LEFT([Product].[Product code].&[foo].membername, 3)`. But you have to iterate over the Product codes to filter in only those which match the criteria.

So instead of `LEFT([Product].[Product code],3) <> 'ALE'`, the below is syntactically correct.

```
FILTER([Product].[Product code].MEMBERS AS prd,
       LEFT(prd.currentmember.name,3) <> 'ALE'
      )
```

You can accommodate the other conditions in trailing `AND` clauses.

```
......FROM(SELECT 
           FILTER([Product].[Product code].MEMBERS AS prd,
           LEFT(prd.currentmember.name,3) <> 'ALE' AND
           LEFT(prd.currentmember.name,3) <> 'DBN' AND
           LEFT(prd.currentmember.name,3) <> 'DBR'
          ) ON 0 FROM [Sales]
```

Of course, there are many more and much better ways to handle such kind of requirements, but this is just to drive home how to correctly do filtering in this case.

Comment: (upped) nice one - would the other conditions then also go in the sub-select : so maybe use axes 0 to 3 in a single sub-select ?